# How to use client.query without JSX components in Apollo Client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to make a query in Apollo Client with React without returning a JSX component, just an object (the `data` object that is received when making a common query to Apollo Server).

I tried using `<Query />` component, but it returns me a React Node and I only need an object. The documentation only explain methods that return JSX components at some point, when all that I'm looking to do is send a request and process the response in a callback.

Actually I'm trying this way (I'm using TypeScript in React):

```
import React from 'react';
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const MY_QUERY = gql`
  query MY_QUERY {
    myQuery {
      attr1
      attr2
    }
  }
`;

const res = ({ client }: { client: any }) =>
  client
    .query(MY_QUERY)
    .then((data: { data: any }) => data);

withApollo(res);

console.log(res);
```

With this, what I'm looking is for a object like

```
{
  "data": {
    "myQuery": [
      {
        "attr1": "something 1...",
        "attr2": "another thing 1..."
      },
      {
        "attr1": "something 2...",
        "attr2": "another thing 2..."
      },
      {
        "attr1": "something 3...",
        "attr2": "another thing 3..."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But what I'm receiving from the browser is

```
ƒ WithApollo(props) {
    var _this = _super.call(this, props) || this;

    _this.setWrappedInstance = _this.setWrappedInstance.bind(_this);
    return _this;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please post the code you currently have. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for code problems. It's unclear what your code currently looks like but it's likely that a component need to be used any way because that's how things interact in React.

Comment: Pleas edit your question and format your code inside of it instead of sending it as a comment

Comment: Ok! I've just put my code

Comment: That's a really weird gql query syntax, does this works in the GQL playground ?  Can you show me the JSX part that uses the result, I'll show you how to use the `Query` node, it's fairly easy

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code to the real way I'm doing it.

Comment: Please edit your question of you want to add relevant code, this is really hard to read

Comment: Alright, let's forget about your request, what are you going to do with the data you are getting ?

Comment: I've just updated!, sorry for that haha. 

I also tried in Graphiql and the query works perfect

Comment: I need it in an array of objects to then passed it to a React Router wrapper

Comment: Ummm, could you paste the class generating the wrapper. Print out an exmaple of the data you will receive and the resulting JSX you want from it

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit ?

Comment: Was a mistake.

I've just update the response I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead

```
class anyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
   state = {
      results: null,
   }
   componentDidMount = async () => {
       const {client} = this.props;
       res = await client.query({query: MY_QUERY});
       console.log(res);
       this.setState({results: res})
   }
   render() {
       // check if any results exist (just an example)
       return results ? <AnyJsx results={results}/> : null;
   }
}
export default withApollo(anyComponent);
```

You were console logging the function instead of calling it to get its result
You may need some lifecycle functions like `componentDidMount` to retrieve data

Comment: Thanks Rachid! I updated the code with your answer but now TypeScript say me that `withApollo` is not expecting to receive a promise as parameter

Comment: the error is: 

Argument of type '({ client }: { client: any; }) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<WithApolloClient<{ client: any; }>>'.

Comment: @ClementeSerranoSutil check, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ClementeSerranoSutil let me know if that help. if you want to add ur logic in life cycle methods JSX won't help you. you will need to use the HOC withApollo.

Comment: What would client be? I'm using `Gatsby` which uses graphql at build time and I don't think it has a client to query from, or I think the client might be local?

Comment: I [asked a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502019/make-graphql-query-outside-a-jsx-component-in-gatsby) if you're interested