# Make graphql query outside a JSX component in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, gatsby

I have a `.ts`(not `.tsx`) file which just exports a json object like

```
const obj = {
    img1: gql_img1,
    img2: gql_img2
}
```

I want `gq1_img1` and `gq1_img2` to be the results of a graphql query

I found a [solution which uses Apollo Client,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620761/how-to-use-client-query-without-jsx-components-in-apollo-client) but it doesn't look like they're using Gatsby and I don't think Gatsby uses a client.

The problem with using `useStaticQuery` is that it's a hook, if I try to use it like in the snippet below, I get `"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:"`

```js
const gql = () => {
    
    const gql = useStaticQuery(graphql
        `query adQuery {
            invoiceNinja300x250: file(
                extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"},
                name: {eq: "IN-300x250-2"}
            ){
                childImageSharp {
                    fluid(maxWidth: 250) {
                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_noBase64
                    }
                }
            },
            invoiceNinja600x300: file(
                extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"},
                name: {eq: "IN-600x300-2"}
            ){
                childImageSharp {
                    fluid(maxWidth: 250) {
                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_noBase64
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
        
        )
    return gql
}

    const GQL = gql()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in your reddit post, if you're not using a page query or static query, you'll need Apollo Client or some other gql client.

> I found a solution which uses Apollo Client, but it doesn't look like they're using Gatsby and I don't think Gatsby uses a client.

Gatsby and GraphQL clients are different things. Gatsby is a React framework for building static websites and uses graphQL to fetch data in various ways.
A GraphQL client is much like fetch or axios, they are libraries used to request, post, update, delete data from a REST API.

Can you explain your use case a bit? Maybe there is a more Gatsby way of doing it.

Comment: Hey, I explain my use case a bit on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62616962/6331353

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the React Context API? On the production Gatsby app I work on that's what we use for global variables like some JSON/object data. It allows you in some sort of high level/layout/data layer component to stuff some values you get from a different file into your app to use with other components.