# Netlify is displaying the html version of my Gatsby website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

The website build is at https://5efbc255ca51be00080b5219--epic-raman-086510.netlify.app/ . It looks like the javascript isn't running, and only the html version(supposed to only be displayed to search engines) is being displayed.

It kinda looks like it might only be the home page.
You can visit `theWebsiteBuildLink/publications`, or `theWebsiteBuildLink/publications` to see it working for other pages.

I've noticed the tab at the top of my browser displays a loading animation indefinately

---

**Update**

So it had something to do with the images being ads. The components were named things like `AdImg` and such, and in a folder called ads. I had adblocker disabled but for some reason this problem kept happening. I changed the name away from "Ad" to a code word and suddenly everything loads right.

It's still really concerning that just because so images named 'Ads' couldn't load, that every image on my website failed loading. Can anyone answer

1. Why images in an ads folder, or created by an ads component were not loading properly, even with adBlocker disabled.
2. Why this caused every other image on my website to fail loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it's because the images were from a folder named ads, or that the component they were made from was named Ad. I changed it away from being ads, to being a codeword. I had ad block disabled prior to this. I don't know why this would have caused the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I see the following stacktrace in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at m (index.js:130)
    at p (index.js:100)
```

Looking at the source it refers to it looks like you have a page with an empty image tag without any parameters, i.e. `<Img />`.

The error message is not great. I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/25371) to Gatsby that at least doesn't crash the page if this happens.

Comment: How did you figure out that there's an empty image tag?

Comment: I couldn't find any empty image tag

Comment: It's not necessarily empty. It may also be that the fixed or fluid property is null. Try removing an image at a time from the page until you find the one that causes the problem.

Comment: How did you find out this thing about the Img tag. All I'm seeing is `SyntaxError: illegal character` and `TypeError: "e is undefined"`. Here's an updated link https://5efbc255ca51be00080b5219--epic-raman-086510.netlify.app/

Comment: Is there any way to view the static folder from the build? So I can check what images are in it?

Comment: I went to the source positions in the stack trace (index.js:130 etc) and tried to figure out what set of events could have led to the error. It's not something you should need to do normally, but in this case the error message was unusable.

Comment: So it turns out it's because the images were from a folder named ads, or that the component they were made from was named Ad. I posted an update. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: I saw your updated link at "https://5efbc255ca51be00080b5219--epic-raman-086510.netlify.app/" and found that last line of `getCurrentSrcData` function cause the above error. But for me, your images loaded successfully in both home page and `publications` page.